# Getting data before 'fromEvent' observable fires

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable created from an event like this: when the user types in the search box, the data is retrieved from the API through an HTTP call and this works fine. But what I want to achieve is to get the initial data, before the user types in the search box.
I have a `files$` variable which holds the observable and I use an `async` pipe to display the list of the files I get from the API.

```
    this.files$ = fromEvent(this.searchBoxFile.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
      // startWith(this.uploadService.getAllFiles(this.searchValFile, 0, this.pageList.size, this.sortBy, this.sortDirection)),
      takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$),
      map((e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        this.isLoading = true;
        return (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value
      }),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((searchVal: string) => {
        return this.uploadService.getAllFiles(searchVal, 0, 100, 'name', 'asc');
      }),
      map(data => data.files),
      tap(() => this.isLoading = false),
      catchError(this.hadleError)
   );
```

So I need to make an initial call before the user starts to search something. I tried with `startWith`, but it doesn't work. Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Small advice: put takeUntil last to avoid rxjs leaks (read further https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startWith is a correct operator. You just used it in a wrong place

```
this.files$ = fromEvent(this.searchBoxFile.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
      takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$),
      map((e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        this.isLoading = true;
        return (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value
      }),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      startWith(this.searchValFile)
      switchMap((searchVal: string) => {
        return this.uploadService.getAllFiles(searchVal, 0, 100, 'name', 'asc');
      }),
      map(data => data.files),
      tap(() => this.isLoading = false),
      catchError(this.hadleError)
   );
```

this code seems to be working